# How do I get data from a SubSonic stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, subsonic

I have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SelectStuff] AS

@param1 int
@param2 int

BEGIN

SELECT [Stuff] FROM TABLE

END
```

I want to run this from SubSonic, and the use the stuff that has been selected. So I do:

```
var db = DB.CreateDB();
var stuffProcedure = db.UspSelectStuff(0,1);
```

Now how do I actually get the data from here?

Answer (score 2):

You can also load a collection and match properties will be populated:

```
ProductCollection coll = new ProductCollection();
coll.LoadAndCloseReader(db.UspSelectStuff(0, 1).GetReader());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute the stored procedure as a data set:

```
var stuffProcedure = db.UspSelectStuff(0, 1).GetDataSet();
```